# Grid View - Binding Data with Data Source at Button Click But Grid is not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in `UpdatePanel` . On button click event I am binding data with Grid view. Data is being binded properly but Grid is not showing.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           bindData();
        }
    }

protected void bindData() 
        {
                    // dv is my data view have rows and columns
                    GridView1.DataSource = dv;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    UpdatePanel.Update();
                }
        }
```

On Button Click Event :-

```
protected void btnUpdateExtensions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        // dv is data view have data with columns and rows
        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
                UpdatePanel.Update();      
        }
```

At page load its binding data properly ad showing `GridView` but at button Click Event its not showing GridView while data source is from same source.

Comment: did u get data on button click? check by putting debug point on click event of gridview..

Comment: @Shirish I am getting data accurately.

Comment: button is out side of update panel or in side of updatepanel?

Comment: @Shirish Inside the Update Panel

Comment: then no need to write UpdatePanel.Update();  and check update panel's update mode <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

Comment: @Shirish I have tried this removed updatepanel.update and dont have any update mode in update panel

Comment: then there is only one condition is remain that there is no data in dataview... check by providing other data source in gridview..

Comment: @Shirish thats why I am posting question here :) . Data Source have data .

Answer (score 1):

Your button is inside of `updatepanel` then just call

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
your button and gridview
</asp:UpdatePanel 

protected void btnUpdateExtensions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
         bindData();
        }
```

No need to write UpdatePanel.Update();

Comment: Try only this and tell me result -->protected void bindData(){GridView1.DataSource = dv;GridView1.DataBind();ViewState["s"]=dv;} on btn click call--> GridView1.DataSource = (DataView)Request.ViewState["s"];GridView1.DataBind()